# Flash cs3 registration screen crashing/not responding after startup - since flash player update 16 May 2013

Tags: flash, adobe, registration, updates, flash-cs3

Flash CS3 has stopped responding after startup.  The registration screen appears but is blank and Flash stops responding.  Windows can not find a solution.

I reinstalled Flash CS3 and checked installed fonts to no avail.

SOLUTION:

After a system restore backdated to 16 May 2013 before the Flash Player update, Flash CS3 appears to be working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bulk of the answer is here thanks to Mylenium:

http://forums.adobe.com/message/1640108?tstart=0#1640108

The file I needed to delete was:

adobe_registration.dll

This is found in:

Program Files/Adobe/Adobe Flash CS3

or wherever you installed Flash.

This stops the error associated with the registration screen.

Hope this helps!